# Can I share 'cache' or 'tmp' directory via itunes share?

Tags: iphone, caching, ios5, file-sharing, tmp

I want to share 'cache' or 'tmp' directory via itunes share... is that possible? if yes then how?

I know I can share 'documents' directory by setting `UIFileSharingEnabled` true in info.plist. Just want to know how to share 'cache' or 'tmp' directory.

**Can someone atleast answer in Yes or No?? will be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats not possible. You can only share files in the documents folder with iTunes.

I tried to create symbolic links in the document folder to files in other directories and that didn't work either.